# Криптография Curve22519

Tags: c#, криптография

Всех приветствую, в криптографии полный ноль, но появилась необходимость расшифровывать поток с удаленного сервера который приходит зашифрованный в кривой Cuver25519-donna, может кто подсказать где взять библиотеку на .net для расшифровки?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.Cryptography/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, но как у вас шифруют в кривой Curve25519? Эта кривая используется в схемах обмена ключами и цифровой подписи. Шифровать на эллиптических кривых никак нельзя. Есть гибридные схемы, типа ECIES, но там собственно шифрование реализовано AES, а эллиптическая кривая используется для генерации ключа.